# How to access to form field in views-exposed-form.html.twig (exposed filters)

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I am trying to customize the template for the exposed filters of a view.

I have created the `views-exposed-form.html.twig` and Drupal loads it fine. For now, I have the standard code:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override of a views exposed form.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - form: A render element representing the form.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_views_exposed_form()
 */
#}
{% if q is not empty %}
  {#
    This ensures that, if clean URLs are off, the 'q' is added first,
    as a hidden form element, so that it shows up first in the POST URL.
  #}
{{ q }}
{% endif %}
{{ form }}
```

and that works fine. Nevertheless, if I try to show only one field of the form (e.g., `twig {{ form.field_city }}`) nothing is shown in the filter block, though the page loads fine and there are no apparent errors.

I am working with Drupal 8.7.7 and PHP 7.3.9.

Any help will be more than welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does `{{ dump(form) }}` have any effect?

Comment: ```{{ dump(form) }}``` seems to be too heavy and breaks the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be an incompatibility with Better Exposed Filters module.